# How to create a dynamic grid using vue?

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, grid

What is the best way to create a grid dynamically with Vue?

I was thinking of using the v-for loop to generate cards on a page for X number of 'modules', but would like to arrange them in rows of 3.

e.g

```
 Card | Card | Card
 Card | Card | Card
```

Comment: posible solutions, uses computed property to reshape your 1D array to 2D array. then v-for twice. or v-for your 1D array with `display:flex` and its children with something like `flex: 0 0 33.333%`

Comment: using CSS grids is a possible solution (ex -> display:grid; grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr);

Comment: @Sphinx Thank you, I like the 'flex: 0 0 33.33%' solution.

Answer (score 23):

You can use [CSS grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), make sure to check [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid).

We'll need to make the container a grid container using `display: grid` and use `grid-template-columns`.

You can create a component that accepts a number prop and then use it in the `repeat()` notation.

`repeat({numberOfColumns}, minmax({minColumnSize}, {maxColumnSize}))`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      cards: [1, 2, 3, 4],
      numberOfColumns: 3,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    gridStyle() {
      return {
        gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${this.numberOfColumns}, minmax(100px, 1fr))`
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    addCard() {
      this.cards.push('new-card')
    },
  },
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

```css
.card-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.card-item {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  padding: 2em;
}

body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Columns: <input v-model.number="numberOfColumns">
  <ul :style="gridStyle" class="card-list">
    <li v-for="(card, index) in cards" class="card-item">
      {{ index + 1 }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button @click="addCard">
    Add card
  </button>
</div>
```