# Vue js V-for for image grid view 3x3

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have an API that returns 9 image URL every time i send a request. I want to display the response images in 3x3 grid but I'm confused how to do it. All I could do is using v-for to loop the image display component horizontally or vertically. Please help me.

Comment: How far did you get? Can you share the code that's returned that you're trying to style? Are you trying to use CSS Grid, flexbox, something else?

Comment: TBH i m stuck at this point because i want to make somethig like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVGfG.png from the json object that i got, but all i can do is make it verticaly down using v-for and what i want to make is v for horizontaly until. 3 col and after the 3rd col it will make a new row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CSS grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), make sure to check browser support.

We'll need to make the container a grid container using display: grid and use grid-template-columns.

You can create a component that accepts a number prop and then use it in the repeat() notation.

repeat({numberOfColumns}, minmax({minColumnSize}, {maxColumnSize}))

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      cards: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
      numberOfColumns: 9,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    gridStyle() {
      return {
        gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${this.numberOfColumns}, minmax(100px, 1fr))`
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    addCard() {
      this.cards.push('new-card')
    },
  },
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

```css
.card-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.card-item {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  padding: 2em;
}

body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Columns: <input v-model.number="numberOfColumns">
  <ul :style="gridStyle" class="card-list">
    <li v-for="(card, index) in cards" class="card-item">
      {{ index + 1 }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button @click="addCard">
    Add card
  </button>
</div>
```

source: [How to create a dynamic grid using vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067287/how-to-create-a-dynamic-grid-using-vue)

Comment: OMG THANKYOU SIR YOU JUST MADE MY DAY God Bless You

Comment: I'm glad that it could help. Make sure to tag the answer as the accepted answer so it can better help people passing by !